# Problems installing dartR and package ‘later’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install dartR to work through at least part of “Introduction to dartR” tutorial.

I am running R version 3.5.1
I have used

```
install.packages("dartR")
```

and got

```
package ‘dartR’ successfully unpacked …
```

Then when I try

```
library(dartR)
```

I get

```
Loading required package: adegenet
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘adegenet’ in loadNamespace(j <- 
i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘later’
Error: package ‘adegenet’ could not be loaded
```

I then used

```
 install.packages("adegenet")
```

I got:

```
 package ‘adegenet’ successfully unpacked …
```

Then repeat

```
library(dartR)
```

I get

```
Loading required package: adegenet
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘adegenet’ in loadNamespace(j <- 
i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘later’
Error: package ‘adegenet’ could not be loaded
```

But after more googling, l tried

```
 install.packages("later", repos = "http://r-forge.r-project.org/")
```

And returned

```
 Warning in install.packages :
package ‘later’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

I know `later` is available on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html#available-packages-L
After a bit more googling, I tried

```
 #An alternative is to install from the github CRAN mirror.
> library(remotes)
> install_github("cran/later")
Downloading GitHub repo cran/later@master
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe'
Content type 'application/x-msdownload' length 108622512 bytes (103.6 MB)
downloaded 103.6 MB

Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
```

Now I am out of ideas. Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: How about `install.packages('later', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`?

Comment: Thanks Weihuang Wong. I used that and got 'later' installed and followed through and got 'mime' and 'permute' installed and now 'adegenet' will load, but it gets stuck on 'dartR', but that is a different problem. Thanks .